# How to use sqlite3.so instead of anddroid.database.sqlite.*

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk

I compiled the sqlite3 amalgamation into Android NDK, and I'm able to use it from my C++ code. However, libsqlite3.a is 2.6MB. This link says the library size should be around 500KB for typical Linux/GCC systems with -O2. I'm using NDK r6b to build, and didn't set an optimization level for the compiler, but the default is -O2. Any idea why my library is so large?

Comment: What link? What SQLite options did you enable/disable?